# Outlines on links in IE9 remains when focus is changed

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have some CSS to change the style of the outline on my page.

```
*:focus{outline: #5ab6df dotted 2px; }
```

But when I tab to different links, part of the outline will remain on previous links.

Any help would be appreciated. 
-IE 9, not running in compatibility mode.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: I also see this issue  in the latest version of Chrome (version 27)

Comment: So this seems to happen on Chrome only when outline-style is set as "auto". (But that's still an issue!)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the outline-property to none in the *-selector?

```
* { outline:none; }
```