# Chrome: Parts of outline on links remain after focus removed (when outline-style is explicitly to "auto")

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, outline

There's possibly no straightforward solution for this, but any suggestions for a workaround or pointers to some documentation of this issue/ behavior is welcome.

Scenario: 
If I apply a custom on-focus CSS style, such as:

```
:focus {outline: 2px auto green; }
```

**Issue**: 
Parts of the outline still show on the previously active links even after focus moves away.

In the screenshot, the last link with the green outline is the currently active element. The rest of the links with small green lines around were active only previously.

[image]

These remaining bits of the outline go away after a few seconds on their own or when you drag the mouse over them (or disturb that area of the page in some other way).

**Context**: 
I am working on a chrome extension for accessibility, and I need to set an explicit style to the active element. The reason I am hoping to use outline-style:auto is that 1) applying any other style except auto (like "solid", "dotted" etc) give [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146707/outline-is-drawn-incorrectly-on-chrome-if-outline-style-is-set-to-solid-and-n) and 2) also, it looks better.

I am aware that outline-style:auto is not supported by other browsers.

Using Chrome 27.

Comment: Similar behavior but for IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387672/outlines-on-links-in-ie9-remains-when-focus-is-changed

Comment: I'll probably end up applying outline-style: solid or something, but I am hoping I can use "auto" for reasons mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You might check to see if an outline-offset is being set.

I had a similar problem, I was using Bootstrap and it was setting:

```
a:focus {outline-offset: -2px;}
```

Doesn't sound like you're using Bootstrap, but maybe something similar is happening for you. I changed it back to the default:

```
a:focus {outline-offset: 0px;}
```

that seemed to work for me. Hope this helps!

(Warning, outline-offset is not supported in IE: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I set an outline and a box shadow. Both seemed to stick to the element.

When I added the outline, I also set the box position to "relative" to make it stand out. For some reason that I can't explain, giving the box a z-index of 1 (bringing it forward) when I set the position to relative completely fixed this issue for me.